# How to fix Error in readBin() using arrow package with SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr, apache-arrow

I am working on SparkR and want to speed up processing using [arrow](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/arrow.pdf) package in Databricks. However, I am getting following error when I execute collect(df) after SparkR::dapply or gapply:

```
Error in readBin(con, raw(), as.integer(dataLen), endian = "big") : Error in readBin(con, raw(), as.integer(dataLen), endian = "big") : 
  invalid 'n' argument
```

I am using [SalesRecords](http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/) data of 5 million, just for example. The code is as below:

```
library(SparkR)

SparkR::sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkr.enabled = "true"))

library(arrow)

arrow::arrow_available()

dfSchema <- structType(structField("Region", "string")
                       ,structField("Country", "string")
                       ,structField("ItemType", "string")
                       ,structField("SalesChannel", "string")
                       ,structField("OrderPriority", "string")
                       ,structField("OrderDate", "string")
                       ,structField("OrderID", "int")
                       ,structField("ShipDate", "string")
                       ,structField("UnitsSold", "int")
                       ,structField("UnitPrice", "int")
                       ,structField("UnitCost", "int")
                       ,structField("TotalRevenue", "int")
                       ,structField("TotalCost", "int")
                       ,structField("TotalProfit", "int")
                      )
spark_df <- SparkR::read.df(path="/FileStore/tables/SalesRecords_5m.csv", source="csv", schema=dfSchema)

# Apply an R native function to each partition.
returnSchema <-  structType(structField("UnitsSold", "int"))

df <- SparkR::dapply(spark_df
                    , function(rdf) { data.frame(rdf$UnitsSold + 1) }
                    , returnSchema
                   )

collect(df)
```

When I switch off arrow by setting **spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkr.enabled** as false then the entire code runs without any error. Therefore, arrow is not working and how can I fix this error?

**Note:** I am using following versions: Spark 3.1.1, arrow 4.0.1, R version 4.0.4

Output of sessionInfo() is:

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SparkR_3.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         magrittr_2.0.1     tidyselect_1.1.0   bit_4.0.4         
 [5] xtable_1.8-4       R6_2.5.0           rlang_0.4.9        fastmap_1.0.1     
 [9] hwriter_1.3.2      tools_4.0.4        arrow_4.0.1        htmltools_0.5.0   
[13] bit64_4.0.5        digest_0.6.27      assertthat_0.2.1   Rserve_1.8-7      
[17] shiny_1.5.0        purrr_0.3.4        later_1.1.0.1      hwriterPlus_1.0-3 
[21] vctrs_0.3.5        promises_1.1.1     glue_1.4.2         mime_0.9          
[25] compiler_4.0.4     TeachingDemos_2.10 httpuv_1.5.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you a partial solution though I'm not exactly sure of the precise cause.

There is something happening here with a mismatch of variable types - you are trying to create a field of type "int" but the code there actually creates a field of type "double".

If you add an 'L' to the value you are adding, does this help?

```
df <- SparkR::dapply(spark_df
                    , function(rdf) { data.frame(rdf$UnitsSold + 1L) }
                    , returnSchema
                   )
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, gives the same error. I also changed the column type to double in the input data and return schema but getting the same error.

Comment: Just to check - if you leave the column type as "int" but change the number to 1L, does that help?  Or alternatively, leave the number as 1 and just change the column type to "double"? If you change them both, it'll cause the same mismatch error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I tested this but getting the same error. No matter if I am adding 1 or 1L and datatype as int or double, the same error shows up. I tested all combinations for the sake of testing!

Comment: That's a shame - I managed to recreate the error locally and then fix it using the change I suggested.  Maybe it's to do with changes in different package versions too.  Which version of the SparkR package itself are you using? There were some changes in 3.1.2 that affected the Arrow integration.

Comment: I am using Spark 3.1.1, arrow 4.0.1, R version 4.0.4

Comment: Would you mind posting the output of running `sessionInfo()` in R?  It's just that the version of Spark and the version of the R package SparkR could be different (and the same with Arrow too!)

Comment: just added in description above

Comment: Are you able to update the version of SparkR you're using to 3.1.2 to see if any of those changes help?

Comment: No issue with versions. I reinstalled arrow package after removing it completely and made sure is present on all worker nodes. It works now but not sure why it was not working before! Thanks